# Coded UI test - pass windows authentication credentials from code - [in Web Application]

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a situation where I want to pass widows authentication to web application.

I faced issue in internet explorer 11/10 that is not asking me for windows authentication credentials when I run functional test and open web application. I found on net that we can make changes in IE security setting and make that happen but in my case that feature is disabled from company I am working.

So, please let me know is there any way I can pass windows authentication credentials from code?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736849/codedui-windows-authentication-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to pass windows credentials through the code.  Your best bet is going to be to have your test agent account added to whatever AD group is required for your testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle Windows authentication to web application in CodedUI by using WinControls. 
Here is my code which works fine:

```
        public void launch88()
        {
            BrowserWindow Browser = new BrowserWindow();
            string url = "http://abcd:8080/xyz/";
            BrowserWindow.Launch();
            Browser.NavigateToUrl(new Uri(url));

            WinWindow securityWindow = new WinWindow();
            securityWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Windows Security",PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            securityWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Credential Dialog Xaml Host", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            securityWindow.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Security");


            WinEdit userName = new WinEdit(securityWindow);
            userName.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "User name", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            userName.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Security");                     
            Mouse.Click(userName);            
            Keyboard.SendKeys("my username");


            WinEdit password = new WinEdit(securityWindow);
            password.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "Password", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);            
            password.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Security");            
            Mouse.Click(password);
            Keyboard.SendKeys("my password");


            WinButton ok = new WinButton(securityWindow);
            ok.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "OK", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);            
            ok.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Security");            
            Mouse.Click(ok);

        }
```